# Inflatable object creation

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I want to make my text looks like an inflatable object, I have seen much artworks like that but it's mostly on C4D, was wondering is there a way to make something like that in blender. thank you[image]

Comment: If you search for Blender Pillow there are a number of tutorials. But basically you create each surface as Cloth, stitch them together and then inflate with a force field. e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TMwQbqKuR_4

Comment: Rob, it would be great if you could make a complete answer for the object he's showing, I don't think it's easy to do it (not as easy as a simple square pillow at least)

Comment: Personally I'd sculpt this and if I needed to make 100s of them I'd make it inside Houdini. The free version can export .obj Unlike Blender Houdini can simulate pressure inside volumes correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions I will give it a try :)